# Android auto update

Tags: android, auto-update

I see a lot of SO questions and answers relating to auto update that amount to the correct answer being "it can't be done without the user's participation". However, many of my apps have the "update automatically" checkbox checked in the Play store and I see them auto-updating and then notifying me in the notification bar that they have, in fact, updated.

So clearly it *can be done... I'd like to know what my various options are for getting my app to have this feature.  Does it need to be in the google Play store? Can it be in some alternate store instead? Is it available to apks that are side loaded... etc.

TIA.

Comment: "I see them auto-updating and then notifying me in the notification bar that they have, in fact, updated." -- no, you do not. You see the Play Store engine updating the apps, then notifying you in the status bar that it, in fact, updated them. That's why the checkbox for auto-update is in the Play Store app, not in the individual apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare, but this distinction is academic. As a developer all I care about is that the app gets auto updated; the precise manner of *how it got auto updated is not important.

Comment: It is far from "academic" when you whine about how I and others point out that "it can't be done without the user's participation". *Only* the Play Store, or other baked-into-firmware updating mechanisms, can do this. Apps cannot do this. You are writing an app. Hence, you cannot do this. While apps can arrange to download updates and trigger the installation of those updates, the user must participate in the update process.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I have to say, Mark, that I find your comment perplexing.  I'm not saying you shouldn't rant if you feel like ranting, but I'm at a loss as to what could have been construed as "whining" in my question or follow up. I was just noting that from a development standpoint (or I guess I should say from *my standpoint) so long as I can achieve the goal of auto updating, it's not really important to me how that goal is achieved. The relevant answer to *my question is that it IS possible. The question remains, however... Is there some specific thing I need to do to make this a reality?

Comment: @CommonsWare, and then as soon as I upload a new version of my app into the store it will be auto distributed to all the devices that have it installed (and auto-update checked)? Or is there any other piece I need added to the app's manifest/code to initiate the update when an update is ready?

Comment: "then as soon as I upload a new version of my app into the store it will be auto distributed to all the devices that have it installed (and auto-update checked)?" -- assuming no permission changes, yes. "Or is there any other piece I need added to the app's manifest/code to initiate the update when an update is ready?" -- no. 323go has the right answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On standard phones, the only way it can be done is through the google play store, and only after the user opts in to automatic updates. It will stop working when the application's permissions are changed. Additionally, google can remove apps at will from your device.

The above applies to all Android devices which have google services and the play store installed. Additionally, apps purchased through the Amazon Appstore for Android are automatically updated on Amazon Kindle Fire devices, and some manufacturers have their own app stores which may include that functionality; Samsung and Lenovo come to mind.

If you control the hardware or have a rooted device, you can create/install a system app which can install any app without user intervention.

Answer (score 0):

Here's more of mechanics of how to than theory.  In practice, this is easy to implement.

In your manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".BcastReciever">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" android:path="com.your.package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then in your Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class BcastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getDataString().contains("com.your.package")){
            Intent startActivityIntent = new Intent(context, Your.class);
            startActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivityIntent.setAction("onboot");
            context.startActivity(startActivityIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also just restart a service instead of firing an activity if that is what you want.

Comment: I think you provided solution for receiving the broadcast of app being updated. But what the question is about How to auto update the application!

Comment: @ShreyaShah Huh?  I don't understand how/why this would get a downvote.  Very strange commment.  This is the gears behind 'how do you update an app' and have it continue running.  For example I have an app on the play store, and when I publish an update, this intent gets fired and my app restarts.  The OP's original question was somewhat vague whether they were looking for the how to do this, or what methods are available to do this with.  I downvoted your comment because of this.